# How to enable CORS on a Netlify deployment?

Tags: deployment, server, cors, netlify

I'm using Netlify to serve some static `.json` files. They load fine in the browser but when I try to fetch them via javascript I get the following error in the console:

> Access to fetch at  (redirected from ) from origin
> 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I checked all the options in my site's settings in the Netlify dashboard and don't see any options to enable CORS, how can this be done?

Comment: Check if [this](https://community.netlify.com/t/access-control-allow-origin-policy/1813) helps

Comment: @SamiHaddad Thanks a lot! Saving this `/*
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in a file called `_headers` (no extension) and putting it at the root next to an index.html (not sure if this bit is needed but I followed the comment) worked. If you want to post that as an answer I'll accept!

Comment: Thanks! Will add one based on your comment.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Add a file called `_headers` next to your index.html with the following content:

```
/*
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

It's better to change it to your actual origin instead of `*` in production.

Comment: Unfortunately, they have shut down this custom header feature. Custom headers apply to the request, not the response,If you are proxying content to your site, custom headers will not be applied to that content.:https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/rewrites-proxies/#custom-headers-in-proxy-redirects

Answer (score 6):

The better approach is using a proxy like this,

Create a file called `netlify.toml` in the root directory of the project. (i.e. next to `index.html`)

```
[[redirects]]
  from = "/<path-to-access-cors-url>"
  to = "<cross-origin-url>"
  status = 200
  force = true
  headers = {X-From = "Netlify"}
[[headers]]
  for = "/*"
  [headers.values]
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin = "*"
```

Now use the URL in your HTTP request like this, `https://your-domain.com/<path-to-access-cors-url>`

**Example:**

Consider, `fakedomain.com` is your domain and you want to request resources from `https://example.com/patha`

```
[[redirects]]
  from = "/pathx"
  to = "https://example.com/patha"
  status = 200
  force = true
  headers = {X-From = "Netlify"}
[[headers]]
  for = "/*"
  [headers.values]
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin = "*"
```

Now use the URL in your HTTP request like this, `https://fakedomain.com/pathx`

Comment: Your example shows to get data from netlify function `https://example.com/patha` using client `https://fakedomain.com/pathx`? The `toml` has to be on the server?

Comment: I want to get data from 2 netlify functions, can you show what to enter in `[[redirects]]`? Do I have to put each function in a new `redirect`?

Comment: the toml file should be checked into source control and available on the server.  For redirects you can capture the * wildcard in the `to` field `https://example.com/one-path/*` and use it as `:splat`in the `from` field like `https://example.com/another-path/:splat`

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing as all other suggestions on here but only works when I run it locally. Once it production it fails.

I had to add the `headers` to the netlify serverless functions as shown below:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://example.com"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ message: "Hello World" })
  };
  return response;
};
```